# Python 2.7 Import libsoundtouch

Tags: python-2.7, import

I want install libsoundtouch ("pip install libsoundtouch"). after install process, everything seems correct, but when I run my script python(2.7) can import this module.
After check I have files in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libsoundtouch".

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import libsoundtouch
```

./home/pi/myprog/scripts/python/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./home/pi/myprog/scripts/python/test.py", line 5, in 
    import libsoundtouch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libsoundtouch/**init**.py", line 9, in 
    from zeroconf import Zeroconf, ServiceBrowser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeroconf.py", line 189
    def current_time_millis() -> float:
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What is your current version of python? Maybe you installed the library in other version of python using pip?

Comment: python --version : Python 2.7.16